# Why are Appledoc references to input parameter classes not being highlighted?

Tags: ios, objective-c, documentation, appledoc

Apple documentation has cross reference for input parameters. You can see that `NSStringEncoding` and `NSError` are highlighted: [image]

But when I use appledoc, there are no cross reference at all: [image]

This is my config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>--company-id</key>
    <string>com.vk</string>
    <key>--create-docset</key>
    <false/>
    <key>--create-html</key>
    <true/>
    <key>--ignore</key>
    <array>
        <string>ThirdParty</string>
        <string>Libraries</string>
        <string>Frameworks</string>
        <string>Testing</string>
    </array>
    <key>--install-docset</key>
    <false/>
    <key>--docset-platform-family</key>
    <string>iphoneos</string>
    <key>--output</key>
    <string>docs</string>
    <key>--project-company</key>
    <string>VK.com</string>
    <key>--project-name</key>
    <string>VK iOS SDK</string>
    <key>--keep-undocumented-objects</key>
    <true/>
    <key>--keep-undocumented-members</key>
    <true/>
    <key>--warn-undocumented-object</key>
    <false/>
    <key>--warn-undocumented-member</key>
    <false/>
    <key>--warn-empty-description</key>
    <true/>
    <key>--warn-missing-arg</key>
    <true/>
    <key>--warn-unknown-directive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>--logformat</key>
    <string>xcode</string>
    <key>--exit-threshold</key>
    <integer>2</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`appledoc` is **not** developed by Apple; it's an [open source project](https://github.com/tomaz/appledoc) by [tomaz](https://github.com/tomaz). It just mimics Apple's docs appearance. So this is normal that all the features of Apple's docs are not available in `appledoc`.

The cross reference feature you are mentioning is indeed [not implemented](https://github.com/tomaz/appledoc/issues/17).